# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException, Target class [admincontrol] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller, laravel-4

My route - `Route::put('/fileupload','admincontrol@fileupload')->name('fileupload');`

My admincontroller code is -

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
session_start();
use Auth;
use App\Imports\fileimport;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Excel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Validator;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class admincontrol extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle the incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }
    public function fileupload(Request $request){
        Excel::import(new fileimport, $request->file);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

My form code is -

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('fileupload')}}">
                        @method('PUT')
                        @csrf
```

Above mention is my code,
im trying to call my upload function via admincontroller from route, but it doesn't work.
i jus included all the required functions i think so
but i couldn't find where i made a mistake and what still need to upload in this.

This shows the error as `Target class [admincontrol] does not exist.`
but i make a admincontrol.php in my controller section.

Someone help me to fix.
Im trying to insert a data into table via csv import.

Comment: Does it change something if you try with this route:
Route::put('/fileupload', [\App\Http\Controllers\admincontrol::class, 'fileupload'])->name('fileupload');
If not, can you show your route file?
Not about your actual problem but you should remove this: session_start();
You should also remove the __invoke() function

Comment: @Thibaut thanks for ur reply, i removed that `session_start() and __invoke()`, also i tried with ur route code, now its shows different error as `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your whlole route file? I guess there is something with other routes.
You can also try to do php artisan route:clear or php artisan optimize:clear
How do you send the form? With a simple button type submit? Can you also show the whole form?

Comment: @Thibaut i jus got it, actually i used the route as `Route::get('/fileupload', [admincontrol::class,'fileupload']);`

Comment: Glad to ear you finally found it. So in fact my first comment was right :)